# Buffer size in WCF service

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

We have a WCF service which executes certain stored procedures and returns the results to the silverlight client. Some of the stored procedures return upto 80K rows.

Given below are the settings in web.config for Service

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
               <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
           </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                receiveTimeout="00:40:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" 
                closeTimeout="00:40:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                <security mode="None"/>
           </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
           <binding name="MyService.MyService.customBinding0">
              <binaryMessageEncoding/>
              <httpTransport/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
     </bindings>
     <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior" 
                   name="MyService.MyService">
              <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" 
                  address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" 
                  contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
           </service>
     </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this for Client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/> 
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="MyService_Behavior">
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
           </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="r1">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" 
                closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" 
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" 
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
                transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
               <security mode="None"/>
             </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
     <client>
        <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService"
            address="http://localhost:8080/MyService/MyService.svc" 
            behaviorConfiguration="r1"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" 
            contract="MyService.IMyService"  />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Whenever the number of records go beyond 20K, the service throws an error as either TimeOut or NotFound. Why do you think this happens n how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to return 80K rows from one call? Maybe refactoring and using "paged" results would be more appropriate?

Comment: I know it sounds absurd but my users are hell bent on having it displayed on the grid (ofcourse, we have them displayed with pagination). Most third party grids like Telerik supports it though

Comment: You ca try to get that data in multipe calls DownloadPage(1) ... n you will get all data but in smaler chunks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like sheer data overload. Pagination, as noted in comments, is a practical solution. If there is a good reason to want the 80k, you could try using a different mechanism to serialize the data. For example, protobuf data is generally *much* smaller than xml, so you might try using that on the wire. However, since this is Silverlight I can't (currently) swap this automatically - you would need to return a `byte[]` or `Stream` and handle the serialization/deserialization explicitly at the server/client. This should drop the bandwidth requirements by a fair whack (even more if you can configure Silverlight to use MTOM - I haven't checked lately, but this wasn't supported in some earlier releases).

Comment: I agree with this answer. Going forward, the best way to display the results would be to fetch smaller amounts of data as the user seeks to next page. But at the moment, I need a quick fix as this issue occurs in a production system.

Comment: @Kev you *might* get lucky and find a way of doing that, but not everything can be addressed with a quick fix. It *may* be quicker to stop spending time looking for a quick fix, and just fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

As your proc returns 80K, you have to add your buffer size at Client end as well.

**readerQuotas**

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
```

This should work. If required increase your buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully used GZIP compression between the Client and the WCF service to increase the number of rows we could pull back. Should also work for your needs.

We used the MS libraries to achieve it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx