# How to send large dataset to WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I want to send a `DataSet` to the WCF service from a WPF application. When I send an empty `DataSet` it works fine. But `DataSet` with 30 `DataTable` it gives me exception of

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

My Operation contract is :

```
  [OperationContract]
  string InsertDataToDatabase(DataSet ds);
```

Which can be the best way to send the `DataSet` to WCF service?

Client `App.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunication" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"  maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:49486/Communication.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunication"
                contract="CommunicationReference.ICommunication" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunication" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service `Web.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConName" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-7;Initial Catalog=ABC; User ID=sa; Password=****"/>        
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment--> 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
           <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information--> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1600" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>  
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: You'll need to adjust your binding settings for the service.  Can you post your service config file?

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what's the problem with the web service. You need to investigate that first. If this is a third party service, request information (or possible limitations of the web service). If it's your service, investigate yourself first.

Comment: @ Strelok, it my local service , i have tested with empty dataset

Comment: Your service may have thrown an exception. Look in the event log.

Comment: Also, will this service be used by any clients other than .NET clients? Then DataSet isn't a good choice. In any case, a set of objects would be more convenient to your consumers than a DataSet.

Comment: We need to see your **service** config - the client config has nothing to do with how much data your service can receive.

Comment: @ John Saunders, as i have mentioned, it will be a WPF application who will send the DataSet. what can be other option

Comment: Please refer this discussion to solve your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337412/buffer-size-in-wcf-service

Comment: You can use a [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) to serialize a class to send to the service.  One of the benefits by doing it that way is that non-.NET clients would be able to use the service as well.

Comment: Might have to enable MTOM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa528822.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recall ever seeing a 400 error message for data size issues, but...there's a few things you can try.

There's a couple of things going on here.  First, according to your service's config file you're on .NET 4.0.  That means you're using default endpoints - you don't have one defined explicitly in the config, so the framework creates one for you.  And it uses the default values for the appropriate binding (`BasicHttpBinding` in this case), which means that even if you change the values in the binding you define, they won't take effect.  Additionally you will receive a default behavior with the default values as well.

Try setting a higher value for `maxReceivedMessageSize` in the binding - the default is 65536 - and `maxStringContentLength` (the default is 8192 ~ 8K).  If you increase the size of `maxStringContentLength` you will also need to increase the size of `maxBufferSize` to the same value (at least).

Now, since you don't have an endpoint explicitly defined, you'll need to either create an endpoint and assign the binding you define to it, or make the definition you have the default.

First, an updated version of your binding (for handling larger data) might look like this (only the relevant parts that need to be changed are shown - I've omitted the rest for brevity).  I've picked a fairly large number - for `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` the max is the max value of an Int64, and for `maxStringContentLength` the max value is the max value of an Int32.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunication" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Next, you need to assign this binding to your service endpoint.  The easiest way, especially if you only have one endpoint, is to make the binding definition above the default.  You do this by simply omitting the `name` attribute in the `binding` element. For example:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Notice there is no `name` attribute in the above (stripped) configuration.

The second way is to create an endpoint and assign the binding configuration you defined to it.  For example:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceName">
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunication"
                contract="MyService.IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I've also seen folks increase the `maxItemsInObjectGraph` attribute of the `dataContractSerializer` element in the service behaviors, though I've never done it.  Based on the MSDN documentation I don't think that would apply in your case, as you're not using any Data Contracts.  However, to try and give you as many options to fix this as possible, you could adjust by defining an endpoint behavior in your behaviors group, like this:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LargeDataBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Again, since you're on .NET 4.0 you'll either need to define this behavior as the default behavior (by omitting the `name` attribute) or assign it to a defined endpoint, like this (using the endpoint example above):

```
<endpoint address=""
          behaviorConfiguration="LargeDataBehavior" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunication"
          contract="MyService.IMyContract" />
```

You might also take a look at [WCF Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: these changes have to do on client side?

Comment: No, only on the service side, because the service is receiving the (large amount of) data.  If the client is going to receive similar large amounts of data back from the service then you would also apply similar changes to the client side.  In this case, based on your question, it sounds like they only need to be applied to the service side.

Comment: after updating your second code binding without name, when i run the svc file, it still display the default values

Comment: i have check inside wcf client config file

Comment: @Arshad - For the purposes of this issue, the changes need to be applied to the service config file, **not** the client config file.  Did you update the service config file? If so, can you edit your question and add your new service config file?

Comment: i have changed only on service side, but checked with WCF Client tool ,config file is showing default values